# c device-driver files_ops struct fields

Tags: c, device-driver

```
struct file_operations hello_fops = {
owner: THIS_MODULE,
read: hello_read,
write: hello_write,
ioctl: hello_ioctl,
open: hello_open,
release: hello_release,
};
```

Here what is the meaning of : after struct field i.e owner:
Somewhere I 've also seen like .owner:=

Also how can I see what are the other available options for "**owner**". I want to give permissions to all to issue ioctl calls.

What is meaning of . here
Can anybody explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{.field=value}
```

is a C99-style initializer.

```
{field: value}
```

is a GCC-style initializer.

`owner` has nothing to do with permissions. Permissions are the normal file permissions, you may want to use an `udev` rule to set appropiate permissions. An `ioctl` call will typically require additional permissions, depending on its meaning, e.g: CAP_NET_ADMIN for some network relted ioctl's.